# Accessing variable from one component ot another

Tags: talend

My name is Naveen, i am getting a bit difficult in setting variable values to different components.I am very much new to talend.
Scenario is, i am having a string variable called a="abc",in X component,now i want to set or access this a variable to b in Y component.Is this possible?
Note:X and Y are custom components.

Thanq all.

Comment: If that custom component has schema, you can pass this variable value to next component or you can use globalMap for saving variables temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

There is an object "globalMap", collection that Talend uses for context variables.

You can put and get references there, like:

globalMap.put("configName", "configValue");

And use it in another component:

x = (String) globalMap.get("configName"));

Note! There are some pre-defined variables, for different component types, e.g. number of rows returned by tOracleInput, etc. You can access them by pressing  +  from java component for example, or from "if" trigger.